# ASP.Net image become unable to open after Upload with AJAX HTMLEditor

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I implemented a functions in AJAXControlToolkit to allow upload of image, but once I uploaded the image, it become not able to open (originally it open without problem in my PC). Note that however, some of the files uploaded without problem.

Below is the upload code

```
protected void tbxContent_HtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string storage = @"/storage/";
                string filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + e.FileName.Substring(e.FileName.IndexOf('.'));

                if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(storage)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(storage));
                }

                // Save your File
                (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload).SaveAs(Server.MapPath(storage + filename));

                // Tells the HtmlEditorExtender where the file is otherwise it will render as: <img src="" />
                e.PostedUrl = storage + filename;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

When I click on the image file at the server, I got the error as below.
[image]

Updated 1:
Seems like all the image details gone after uploaded to server, previously it exists my local PC.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked this: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27655

Comment: @PeterKiss, indeed.. when the filename contains unicode (Chinese in my case), the image details will be gone and not able to open. Though the file size remain the same.